# Should BaseType of System.Object be the same as interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

- **summary**

  `typeof(ISomeInterface).BaseType` is `null`; `typeof(object).BaseType` is also `null` by definition. Thus:

  ```
  typeof(object).BaseType==typeof(ISomeInterface).BaseType -> true
  ```

  It could (semantically) mean `System.Object` is an interface, too, doesn't it? In c#, all classes inherit from `System.Object`, but interfaces do not. Interfaces in fact are contracts, not the base type of any class, and can only derive from other interfaces.

  So I'm wondering whether `typeof(object).BaseType` should be the same as interfaces?
- **explanation**

  I thought this in the way of elementary mathematical logic. I treated `null` as `0` and `typeof(object)` as `1`, so that finding the base types of some type are just like finding the factors of a number.

  Under this assumption, `null` could be the derivation of any type, like `0` is a multiple by a factor of any number. And `typeof(object)` would be the base type of any class, like `1` is a factor of any number even itself. The actual returning `null` of `typeof(object).BaseType`, however, broke this assumption. This seems saying that `0` is a factor of `1` but not of any other number.

  Further, if we use a method to find the base type of `SomeType` recursively, we cannot always say `SomeType` is not a class because of its `BaseType` is `null`, `typeof(object).BaseType` is also `null`.

  It seems paradoxical if

  ```
  typeof(object).BaseType==typeof(object) -> true
  ```

  to present that its base type is itself, but isn't that exactly the difference between entities and contracts?

---

**update:**

I originally stated that:

> It could mean `System.Object` is an interface, too, doesn't it?

What I want to say is **it seems confused**. It's my fault of the poorly expressed description, and sorry to cause the answers focused on that.

Comment: I think this is logical. The base type for an interface is null, as you concluded yourself. Also, System.Object is the base of all .net classes, and itself, does not have a base class, so that results in a null as well. Seems logical to me.

Comment: The current king of France is a non-existing person. The current king of Siam is a non-existing person. If two things are both equal to the same thing, then they are equal to each other. **Therefore, the king of France is also the king of Siam.** Is that logic correct?  Remember, "null" means "does not exist" in this context.

Comment: *Is it correct that typeof(object).BaseType returns null like an typeof(ISomeInterface).BaseType does?* Those two cases return null [by definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It is a boundary case, and some developer at microsoft thought that returning **null** in both cases would be the proper solution.

Comment: Actually the "*King of France*" argument rests on whether you define "non-existence" to be a value or an attribute (because in English "***is***" is ambiguous as to which is intended).  If you define non-existence to be a value, then yes they are the same.  But if you define it to be an *attribute* then no they are not the same.  Thus "*the queen of England is a Queen*" and "*the queen of Denmark is a Queen*" are both true statements.  Nonetheless, they are still different people.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I like the equivocation: "Nothing is better than Filet Mignon.  Fast-food burger is better than nothing.  Therefore, fast-food burger is better than Filet Mignon."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `BaseType` property returns the base type for types that have *a* base type. For all other types, it returns a value indicating that the type does not have *a* base type. You posed the following expression in the original question:

`typeof(object).BaseType == typeof(SomeInterface).BaseType`

Then you suggested that since this expression is true, `Object` and `SomeInterface` appear to have the same base type. However, your conclusion is flawed because it assumes the existence of a base type for both `Object` and `SomeInterface`, when the documentation for the method explicitly states that this is not the case.

Comment: If an instance of type `T` is always an instance of `T` (trivially true), then any statement that `T` is the base type of `T` is redundant. `System.Object` does not, and cannot, have a base type which is not trivially redundant. It *is* based on itself because it *is* itself.

Answer (score 7):

[Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0b0thckt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are two different things. The following expression:

```
typeof(object).BaseType == typeof(SomeInterface).BaseType
```

Is true only because the following is also true:

```
null == null
```

And, by definition, [BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns null if the current type represents the object class or an interface.

> It could mean System.Object is an interface, too, doesn't it?

Actually not, because an interface contains only the signatures of methods, but not their implementation. You can think an interface as a contract that classes must implement.

Answer (score 4):

`typeof(object).BaseType` returns `null` because of MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx);

> Object is the only type that does not have a base type, therefore null
>   is returned as the base type of Object.

You can't use it `BasType` property with an `Interface`. Let's look at this piece of code;

```
using System;

namespace Programs
{
    public interface IBar { }
    public interface IFoo : IBar { }

    public  class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type[] types = typeof(IFoo).GetInterfaces();

            foreach ( var t in types )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Programs.IBar

---

Interfaces inherit from zero or more base interfaces; therefore, this property returns `null` if the `Type` object represents an `interface`. The base interfaces can be determined with [`GetInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx) or [`FindInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.findinterfaces.aspx).

---

Let's look at one more code;

```
using System;

namespace Programs
{
    public interface IBar { }
    public interface IFoo : IBar { }
    public interface IZoo : IFoo { }

    public  class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type[] types = typeof(IZoo).GetInterfaces();

            foreach ( var t in types )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

> Programs.IFoo
>
> Programs.IBar

---

> The question is, we got the null either with typeof(object).BaseType.
>   It could means System.Object is an interface, too, doesn't it?

No, [System.Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) is not an Interface. It is a class. It supports all classes in the .NET Framework class hierarchy.

Comment: `BaseType` also returns `null` for pointer types (e.g. `typeof(int*)`) and byref types (e.g. `typeof(int).MakeByRefType()`). The documentation does not indicate this.

Comment: @KenKin No, it's not. In an unsafe code, a type may be a pointer type. Look at [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. 
But, doesn't unsafe code breaks the rules of OO?

Comment: @KenKin No, not true. Read [Safer unsafe code for .NET](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=78028)

Answer (score 4):

Just a note: interfaces are not types in a sense that classes and structs are! Interfaces do not exist by themselves.

Classes and structs are types for data(code) but interfaces are types for types. They can be used for categorizing other types. They force other types to follow a protocol and nothing more. They are just a layout, a definition, a contract; not an existing thing.

Comment: Yes, and interfaces do not derive from `System.Object`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of types in .net which are "special", including `System.Object`, `System.ValueType`, and `System.Enum`, whose behavior in the inheritance hierarchy is unique.  For example, any type `T` which derives from `System.ValueType` will a value type, unless `T` is either `System.ValueType` or `System.Enum`, both of which are class types.  The lack of a base type for `Object` can probably be viewed in similar light--every type which lacks a base type is an interface, except for `System.Object` which is an oddball.

Comment: Thanks for answering a question have already an accepting answer.

Comment: @KenKin: I thought it noteworthy that there are a number of places in the interface that effectively say "All types that share some characteristic with XX, *except for XX itself*, have some characteristic YY", but none of the other answers seemed to mention such examples.

Answer (score 1):

> "It could (semantically) mean System.Object is an interface, too,
>   doesn't it?"

No, that assumption relies on these assumptions:

- The BaseType property always returns the base type of a type
- Two types having the same base type are the same

When `typeof(object).BaseType` returns `null` it doesn't mean that the base type is `null`, it means that there is no base type at all. So, when `typeof(ISomeInterface).BaseType` also returns `null` it doesn't mean that it has the same base type as `object`, it means that it too has no base type at all.

Even if `object` and interfaces had the same base type, it wouldn't mean that `object` is an interface. The types `int` and `double` for example have the same base type, but that doesn't mean that they are the same.

Comment: The first bullet point is what I suppose it should be. The second bullet point, it would mean each of them *is* their base type, that is, an (instance of) `int` *is* a `ValueType` and a `double` *is* a `ValueType` also, not an `int` is a `double`. Thus, an instance of `SomeType` implies it is also an instance of `SomeType's base type`. However, `BaseType` of `System.Object` doesn't return `System.Object`, that breaks the assumption, and one cannot use `BaseType` to determine whether `SomeType` is a class or not.

Comment: @KenKin: The first bullet point is not true, because there isn't always a base type. The second bullet point would be needed to take you from the assumption "object has the same base type as interface" to "object is an interface".

Comment: Exactly, and that's why I wondered it's designed in this way; I thought that would make `BaseType` lesser useful. Most of all, thank you very much, for answering an old question.